# Numerical integration graph and convergence

Tags: numerical-integration, code-review, code-request

I am trying to do the following integral numerically, My question is that, after the integration, when I tried to plot, the plot does not show anything on it. What did I do wrong?

Furthermore, I understand that this integral converges very slowly, is there any way to improve it (essentially I want to integrate s from -infty to +infty and t from 0 to +infty, and this will give me the typical warning for slow convergence)?

Any help will be appreciated. It is fine if you want to help me with one question or another.

Thank you very much for reading my question!

```
P[s, t] = (1/(16*Pi^2*u^(1/2)*
   t^3))*((4 t (I s + t^2) - (s - I (-2 + t) t) (s - 
       I t (2 + t)) (Log[-2 + (I s)/t + t] - 
       Log[2 + (I s)/t + t]))/(8 t^2) + (4 t (-I s + t^2) - (s + 
       I (-2 + t) t) (s + I t (2 + t)) (Log[-2 - (I s)/t + t] - 
       Log[2 - (I s)/t + t]))/(8 t^2));

rat = Rationalize[FullSimplify[P[s, t]]];

H[u_?NumericQ] := 
 u^(5/2)*NIntegrate[
 t^2/2*(Log[1 - rat] + rat/(1 - rat)), {t, 0, 3}, {s, -10, 10}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 5]

Plot[H[u], {u, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: What do you get for `H[-1]` or `H[1]`?

Comment: it says the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values. Sorry, I am a beginner; what should I do?

Comment: The simplest fix is to redefine `rat`: `Clear[rat]; rat[u_] = Rationalize[FullSimplify[P[s, t]]];` and replace `rat` in `H` by `rat[u]`. The problem this solves is that the def. of `H` creates a rewrite-rule that replaces every literal occurrence of `u` by a numeric value. The expression `rat` is just `rat` and has no `u` in it; only when `rat` is evaluated, does `u` show up. It's a question of scope and when things are evaluated. The replacement of `u` is done first; then `NIntegrate` is evaluated, and then the integrand is evaluated, during which `u` shows up without a numeric value.

Comment: There's another subtle complication, but I'll leave it there, since that's already a lot for someone just starting *M*.  Now evaluate `H[-1]` and `H[1]`, and you'll see more reasons `H` cannot be plotted.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the fix! It seems that for negative u, the integration goes well but the result become complex due to the square root on u. But for positive u, the integral converges too slowly. Is this the reason that you are referring to?

Comment: Yes.  You can plot `Abs[H[u]]`, `Re[H[u]]`, etc., for negative `u`.  For positive `u`, you have to work on the integral, and I don't have a quick fix for that.